# Use add_foreign_key to reference the same model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Car

I want to create a relation like following

```
belongs_to :primary_car, class_name: 'Car'
has_many :secondary_cars, class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'primary_car_id'
```

How can I write a migration with the use of add_foreign_key specifically, in order to create the foreign key primary_car_id to my can model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new table or adding a column on an existing table with `t.references`:

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :cars do |t|
      # aka belongs_to
      t.references :primary_car, foreign_key: { to_table: 'cars' }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddPrimaryCarToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_table :cars do |t|
      # aka belongs_to
      t.references :primary_car, foreign_key: { to_table: 'cars' }
    end
  end
end
```

To add a foreign key constraint to an existing column:

```
class AddForeignKeyToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    # the column cars.primary_car_id must already exist
    add_foreign_key :cars, :cars, column: :primary_car_id
  end
end
```

This is known as a [self-join](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) or self referencing association.